# How to handle two Sequelize create request to update two different tables in the database using NodeJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I am using Sequelize and NodeJs to create an API endpoint that updates the two different tables in the database. The front-end is sending form data (text/files). (1) I am extracting the text data and updating the table called **shipmentBooking**, the first table id is used as foreign key in the 2nd table. simultaneously I am sending the files to the s3 bucket and getting the file paths as an array. (2). once file paths are received I am using the below function to update the 2nd database table called **shipmentDoc** that has **shipmentId** as a foreign key. the entire thing is working fine except it does not update the foreign key in the 2nd table.

```
router.post('/add', upload.array('file'), async (req, res) => {

    const shipmentBooking = ShipmentBooking.create({
        bookingType: req.body.bookingType,
        bookedBy: req.body.bookedBy,
        bookingUserId: req.body.bookingUserId
    })

     try{
            const newShipment = await shipmentBooking
            console.log('#############')
            console.log(newShipment.id)
        
            const results = await s3Uploadsv2(req.files, req.body.bookingUserId) 
    
            const addedShipmentDoc = await Promise.all(results.map(result => ShipmentDocs.create({
                shipmentId: newShipment.id,
                additionalDoc1: result.Location
            })));
            return res.json({status: 'success', newShipment, addedShipmentDoc})
        } catch({error}){
            console.log(error)
        }
})
```

**Model & Associations:**

```
const ShipmentBookings = db.define('shipmentbookings', {
    id:{
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER(255),
        autoIncrement: true,
        allowNull: false,
        primaryKey: true
    },
    UUID:{
        type: DataTypes.UUID,
        defaultValue: Sequelize.UUIDV4
    },
    bookingType: { // invidiual, business
        type: DataTypes.STRING(100),
        allowNull: false,
    },
    bookedBy: { // staff, customer
        type: DataTypes.STRING(100),
        allowNull: false,
    },
    bookingUserId: { // user id of customer
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER(255),
        allowNull: true,
    }
},{
    freezeTableName: true
})


const ShipmentDocs = db.define('shipmentdocs', {
    id:{
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER(255),
        autoIncrement: true,
        allowNull: false,
        primaryKey: true
    },
    UUID:{
        type: DataTypes.UUID,
        defaultValue: Sequelize.UUIDV4
    },
    billOfLading: {
        type: DataTypes.TEXT('medium'),
        allowNull: true,
    },
    dockReceipt: {
        type: DataTypes.TEXT('medium'),
        allowNull: true,
    },
    additionalDoc1: {
        type: DataTypes.TEXT('medium'),
        allowNull: true,
    },
    additionalDoc2: {
        type: DataTypes.TEXT('medium'),
        allowNull: true,
    },
    additionalDoc3: {
        type: DataTypes.TEXT('medium'),
        allowNull: true,
    },
    additionalDoc4: {
        type: DataTypes.TEXT('medium'),
        allowNull: true,
    },
    additionalDoc5: {
        type: DataTypes.TEXT('medium'),
        allowNull: true,
    }
},{
    freezeTableName: true
})

ShipmentBookings.hasOne(ShipmentDocs ,{foreignKey: 'shipmentId'})
ShipmentDocs.belongsTo(ShipmentBookings ,{foreignKey: 'shipmentId'})
```

**ShipmentDocs Table Image**
[image]

Comment: Please show model definitions and associations

Comment: ShipmentBookings.hasOne(ShipmentDocs ,{foreignKey: 'shipmentId'}) I tried this .HasMany association as well. but no luck.

Comment: Is the ShipmentDocs record creating at all?

Comment: @ChigozieIjomah yes records are adding to ShipmentDocs, just the shipmentId column is not populating.

Comment: Can you confirm that the column actually exists in your MYSQL Workbench? Perhaps you made the change to include associations after the database has been synced.

Comment: @ChigozieIjomah Updated question, I have added the screenshot showing the table with shipmentId as a foreignKey. I tried to update the foreign key column MANUALLY and it works. just not populating through the code provided above.

Comment: All seems right with your code except for the fact that ShipmentBookings is supposed to have a hasMany association with ShipmentDocs.

Answer (score 0):

if the             `console.log(newShipment.id)`
is working as expected,

How about you create the ShipmentBooking within a promise and then after excecuting it, within the "then" ( or "final" ) you run the addedShipmentDoc create query.

Else, console logg the newShipment to see if it has an id field.

Comment: console.log(newShipment.id) is working and printing the right outout. however, when adding the ShipmentDoc record, it does not.

Comment: please try the new promises method as I briefly described above.

Comment: You mean within  await Promise.all(results.map(result => .... ?